# Interpretation using First-order logic

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic

The following formula:
$$\forall x(\forall y (\forall z((x=y)\lor(y=z)\lor(z=y) )))$$
is interpreted as "there are at most two elements ". how can we write a formula for "there are exactly two elements"?

I have the idea that this is done as follows:
we can find two elements that are different, but if we take more than two elements then the third is equal to one of the other two.

However, I don't have a very clear idea how to write this as a formula

Comment: figure out how to write "there are at least two elements" and take the conjunction of that and the one you have written above.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd tackle this by using a variation on your sentence for "there are at most 2 elements" and then also requiring there to be at least 2. This gives exactly 2.

$$
\forall x(\exists y ((y\neq x) \land \forall z((y=z)\lor(x=z))))
$$

In English: For all $x$ there's a $y$ that is different to $x$ (at least two elements), and any third element is equal to one of the other two (at most two elements).

Comment: The request is not that for every number, there is a distinct number, and no other.  We have to assert the existence of two numbers, not necessarily the existence of two numbers given each and every x.

Comment: @amWhy I'm not sure I see how this is different? Saying that for all elements there is exactly one other element is equivalent to saying there exists exactly two elements, at least in my head.

Comment: If you allow empty structures, then this is wrong, since it is also true if there are 0 elements.

Answer (score -1):

$$\exists x \exists y \big(x\neq y \land \forall z(z=x \lor z=y)\big)$$

Comment: This asserts the existence of two elements that are different, and given any third proposed element, it must equal one of the two elements.  Hence, there exist two unique elements.